# Is it safe or an okay practice to spawn process from ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

So I have an ASP.NET web service that needs to use a command line application to accomplish some work.  It can run as the same user as the ASP.NET web service, so no impersonation is necessary.  Is it safe\good practice to spawn a process in ASP.NET?

Using an external scheduling program that calls the command line application seems like extra overhead.  The transformation may also involve switching to asynchronous communication from synchronous.  It seems like a bad idea for the web service to add a job to be scheduled and then wait, via the service polling scheduler, for that job to complete.  Launching the process directly would simplify all of this, but only if it is a good\okay idea to do so.

Comment: I've done this before with the process object, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently problematic with having ASP.NET launch processes so long as the web worker has the appropriate permissions to do so on the server. The only thing to be mindful is whether or not ASP.NET should wait for processes it starts to complete. Likewise, if it is going to launch non-self-closing applications, be sure you aren't opening too many instances simultaneously such that IIS will become resource-deprived.